# CS50 Pset4 Sepia Filter, where is the bug? The code doesn't pass the CS50 tests

Tags: cs50

So this is the code I have for Pset4 for the Sepia filter...it's heading in the right direction but I've been trying to figure out why it isn't passing the tests. Cannot filter a simple 3 x 3 image or complex 3 x 3 image or the 4 x 4 image. Trying to figure out where the bug is, any tips would be wonderful!

```
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {

        // get values of each colour in the image
        int red = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
        int blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        int green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;

        // find average of the pixel RBG colors
        float average = (round(red) + round(blue) + round(green)) / 3;
        average = round(average);

        //puts the value average into the pixel colors
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = average;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average;
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average;
    }
}
return;
```

}

```
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width]) 
{ 
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
      {
        //gets the values of each color in the image
        int red = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
        int blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        int green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;

        // gets the sepia value of the pixels
        int sepiaRed = round(0.393 * red + 0.769 * green + 0.189 * blue);


        int sepiaGreen = round(0.349 * red + 0.686 * green + 0.168 * blue);


        int sepiaBlue = round(0.272 * red + 0.534 * green + 0.131 * blue);


        if (sepiaRed >= 256)
        {
            sepiaRed = 255;

        }

        if (sepiaGreen  >= 256)
        {
            sepiaGreen = 255;

        }


        if (sepiaBlue  >= 256)
        {
            sepiaBlue= 255;

        }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = sepiaRed;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sepiaBlue;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sepiaGreen;


    }
    return;
}
```

}

Comment: can you post the whole file so someone can compile/run/debug for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, without seeing more of the code. But shouldn't these three ifs at the end be placed before you save their values to the image? Like this:

```
...
        if (sepiaRed >= 256)
        {
            sepiaRed = 255;

        }

        if (sepiaGreen  >= 256)
        {
            sepiaGreen  = 255;

        }


        if (sepiaBlue  >= 256)
        {
            sepiaBlue  = 255;

        }

        image[i][j].rgbtRed = sepiaRed;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sepiaBlue;
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sepiaGreen;
...
```

First You check if calculated values are not higher than 255. Then save these values to the image.
Also you should replace 'else if' with 'if' to check all 3 values not up to one. And then edit value of sepiaRed, sepiaBlue, sepiaGreen not red, blue, green. 
I'm not sure if I get right what that function suppose to do.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the math function round(), mine just working fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
        //gets the values of each color in the image
        int red = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
        int blue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        int green = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;

        // gets the sepia value of the pixels
        int sepiaRed = round(0.393 * red + 0.769 * green + 0.189 * blue)  ;


        int sepiaGreen = round(0.349 * red + 0.686 * green + 0.168 * blue) ;


        int sepiaBlue = round(0.272 * red + 0.534 * green + 0.131 * blue) ;




        if (sepiaRed >= 256)
            {
                sepiaRed = 255;

            }

        if (sepiaGreen  >= 256)
            {
                sepiaGreen = 255;

            }


        if (sepiaBlue  >= 256)
            {
            sepiaBlue= 255;

            }
        image[i][j].rgbtRed = sepiaRed;
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sepiaBlue;
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sepiaGreen;


    }

}
```